# Tapping status bar doesn't scroll table view to top

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, scroll

Ok, I've read almost every single post about this issue, and they all say the same thing:

In the whole view hierarchy, only one scroll view (or subclass) should have `scrollsToTop` set to `YES` and the rest should be `NO`. When my view loads, I recursively iterate the whole view hierarchy just as many answers suggest, setting `scrollsToTop` to `NO`, then I only set my table view's `scrollsToTop` to `YES`, but still, it doesn't scroll when I tap the status bar. I've overridden:

```
-(BOOL)scrollViewShouldScrollToTop:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    return YES;
}
```

But it's not even called even though my view controller is the scroll view delegate of my table view.

I do have cells with text views, and when the container cell awakes from nib, I also set their `scrollsToTop` property to `NO` immediately, and there are no other views deriving from scroll view.

Why would it not work?

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, I've never set scrollsToTop on any table view controller I've ever used, and they all do this by default. Maybe all this recursive view hierarchy stuff is what is actually causing the problem. I just looked at all the apps I've written, and all of them work fine without ever touching scrollsToTop, and many of them have embedded scrollViews/textViews/etc in them. Perhaps try commenting out all that scrollsToTop code and trying it then?

Otherwise, how are you building this tableview? Is it with a nib or is this a normal UITableViewController?

Comment: initially there was no `scrollsToTop` code for that at all. but it wasn't working, that's why I tried setting `scrollsToTop`.

the table view is inside a regular `uiviewcontroller`.

Comment: Perhaps you could try using a normal UITableViewController?

Comment: I can't. I have many custom controls inside the view controller.

Comment: Ahh.. I suppose a potential hack is to put a tap gesture recognizer on top of the status bar?

Comment: Yeah, it could be done as a last resort. But it's too hacky, I'd prefer a more "approved" approach.